# everything related to maven is missing from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

For some reason everything related to maven has disappeared from my eclipse kepler installation. I can't update the project or build it, I can't start a new maven project and there is no trace of any maven related menu.

Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the Eclipse MarketPlace to see if the Maven Integration for Eclipse is installed. If not, maybe you can install it. If it is installed, I can not help you, but my recomendation would be to get a new Eclipse from their web.